# Broken links help with site

Tags: javascript

We've run a report via Alexa and identified some type of issue where a number of pages have /js/respond.src.js at the end of the url. This is being read as a broken link. Our concern is this is impacting our search engine placement. We have no identifiable performance issue but just want to find the root of this error so we can resolve it. I've recently taken over the website which uses a custom theme.

Any help getting getting to the bottom of this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your text editor on your theme and plugin files to search for the `/js/respond.src.js` in the source code.

If in a theme, then create a Child Theme and modify that php file. (Any changes you make to a theme's code will be overwritten in the next theme update.)

If it is a plugin, then contact the plugin author to have them fix their code. But I suspect the theme code first.

Comment: Thanks for the message, Rick. The only occurrence I can find of this line is in the header.php file 

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.src.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
   .gradient {
    filter: none;
   }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->

Comment: That code assumes that the file is in the 'js' folder of the theme folder. I think it is just some javascript file that loads some responsive CSS. If the file is being loaded properly (you can determine with Firebug or other dev tools), then there is no worry. And the code only loads if the user's browser version is greater-than IE9. Shouldn't affect your SEO at all. Try modifying that line (temporarily) by changing it to 
      src="./js/respond.src.js" 
(putting a './' in front to indicate 'current folder'). But, it is an issue that the theme author should fix.